# Splitting csv comma delimited values

Tags: python, csv

I have csv file, which information (id and text) in row's looks like in example below:

```
Field1:
Text:
1, A,A,A,B

Field2:
Text:
2, A,B,C,C
```

My desired output:

```
Field1: Field2:    Field1:   Field2:
ID:      Text:       ID:      Text:
1         A           2         A
1         A           2         B
1         A           2         C
1         B           2         C
```

How can i do that via python ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do what your question asks:

```py
with open('infoo.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    records = []
    rows = [[x.strip() for x in row.split(',')] for row in f.readlines()]
    i = 0
    while i < len(rows):
        gotOneOrMoreRows = False
        if len(rows[i]) == 1 and rows[i][0].startswith('Field'):
            gotOneOrMoreRows = True
            i += 1
            if i < len(rows) and len(rows[i]) == 1 and rows[i][0] == 'Text:':
                gotOneOrMoreRows = True
                i += 1
                row = rows[i]
                records.append([[row[0], row[i]] for i in range(1, len(row))])
        if not gotOneOrMoreRows:
            i += 1

    with open('outfoo.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as g:
        tab = '\t'
        g.write(f'{tab.join(["Field 1:"+tab+"Field 2:" for record in records])}\n')
        g.write(f'{tab.join(["ID:"+tab+"Text:" for record in records])}\n')
        for i in range(len(records[0])):
            g.write(f'{tab.join(colPair[i][0]+tab+colPair[i][1] for colPair in records)}\n')

# check the output file:
with open('outfoo.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    print('contents of output file:')
    [print(row.strip('\n')) for row in f.readlines()]
```

Output:

```
contents of output file:
Field 1:        Field 2:        Field 1:        Field 2:
ID:     Text:   ID:     Text:
1       A       2       A
1       A       2       B
1       A       2       C
1       B       2       C
```

Note that this kind of thing may be easier using pandas.

Comment: I'am really sorry, i wrote question bad, this is not, whaw i really wanted ;/. Kind a new here and python, so

Comment: I notice you changed your question significantly. Normally, you should ask a new question in this case. I have already put work into answering your first question in the hope of having you mark my answer as "accepted". While I (and perhaps others) would be willing to help with your new question, I will be more likely to do this after you accept the answer to your original question (assuming you agree that it answered the question you asked, though not the updated question you intended).

Comment: Feel free to put a link to your new question in the comments here, so I will know that you have asked it, and I will do my best to answer it as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72330260/splitting-rows-in-csv-with-comma-separated-values